# A sufficient condition for $f$ to have polynomial growth

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\alpha z\bar z+\beta z+\bar \beta \bar z+\gamma\geq 0, \forall\ z\in\mathbb C$, where $\alpha,\gamma \geq 0$, $\beta\in\mathbb C$. Show that 
$$f(z)\leq (1+z\bar z)(\alpha+\gamma).$$

I thought it should be proved by Schwarz lemma. However, I could not get that result now...

Comment: The Schwarz lemma is not applicable [unless $\alpha = \beta = 0$], since $f$ is not holomorphic. Can you manipulate $$(\alpha+\gamma)(1+z\overline{z}) - f(z)$$ in such a way that you see it is always a non-negative real number?

Comment: @DanielFischer $$(\alpha+\gamma)(1+z\overline{z}) - f(z)=\alpha-\gamma z\bar z-\beta z-\bar \beta \bar z...$$So I could not show it $\geq 0$...

Comment: You have a sign error, $\alpha +\gamma z\overline{z} - \beta z - \overline{\beta}\overline{z}$. But your solution is much neater.

Answer (score 1):

Thank @ Daniel Fischer. But I have not got the answer.

From the inequality
$$f(z)\geq 0$$
we have 
$$z\bar z f(-1/\bar z)\geq 0$$
add together we just get get $(1+z \bar z)(\alpha+\gamma)\geq 0$.